# Como construir uma queryset que retorne apenas os carros com a ultima revisão aprovada?

Tags: python, django, django-1.8

Estou querendo criar uma *queryset* que retorne apenas os carros que tiveram a ultima revisão aprovada. Sabe-se que podem haver n carros, e cada carro tem um histórico de revisões, logo podem haver n revisões para cada carro.

```
class Carro(models.Model):
    marca = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Revisao(models.Model):
    carro = models.ForeignKey(Carro)
    data = models.DateField()
    aprovado = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Atualmente estou realizando um algoritmo não muito performático, com a seguinte lógica:

```
lista_de_aprovados = []
for carro in Carro.objects.filter(revisao=True):
    try:
        carro_aprovado = carro.revisao_set.filter(aprovado=True).latest('data')
    except ObjectsDoesNotExist:
        pass
    else:
        lista_de_aprovados.append(carro_aprovado)
carros_aprovados = Carros.objects.filter(id__in=[l.pk for l in lista_de_aprovados])
```

Existiria um modo de realizar isso apenas com uma queryset? Estou usando **Django 1.8** e o problema é que estou realizando essa mesma lógica mais de uma vez e isso está deixando um pouco lento na hora de carregar a página. Como eu disse anteriormente, a idea é uma queryset que retorne apenas os carros que tiveram a ultima revisão aprovada.

```
Carros.objects.filter(revisao=True).filter(...logica)
```

Comment: Quando você diz "a última revisão aprovada" significa que podem existir revisões aprovadas, com outra subsequente não aprovada? Ou a aprovada é sempre a última? Dei uma resposta baseado no primeiro cenário - que funciona também pro segundo, é claro, mas é sub-ótima nesse caso (bastaria ver se existe *alguma* revisão aprovada...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, selecione a maior data usando `annotate`:

```
from django.db.models import Max, F

Carro.objects.annotate(max_data=Max('revisao__data'))...
```

Em seguida selecione as revisões que tanto tem data igual à máxima quanto são aprovadas:

```
.filter(revisao__data=F('max_data'), revisao__aprovado=True)
```

O resultado será uma query tipo esta:

```
SELECT "app_carro"."id", "app_carro"."marca", MAX("app_revisao"."data") AS "max_data"
FROM "app_carro" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "app_revisao" ON ( "app_carro"."id" = "app_revisao"."carro_id" )
    INNER JOIN "app_revisao" T3 ON ( "app_carro"."id" = T3."carro_id" )
WHERE T3."aprovado" = True
GROUP BY "app_carro"."id", "app_carro"."marca", T3."data"
HAVING T3."data" = MAX("app_revisao"."data");
```

Ou seja, o `OUTER JOIN` garante que todas as revisões sejam buscadas, e a data máxima das mesmas seja salva em `max_data`, enquanto o `INNER JOIN` garante que somente carros com revisões aprovadas sejam retornados, desde que essa revisão possua a maior data dentre as presentes (i.e. igual a `max_data`).

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu buscava, excelente.