# Total e subtotal em template de Django usando listas pré definidas

Tags: django, django-templates

Como eu faço para calcular o subtotal e o total por coluna?

#### views.py

```
def soma_tuplas(a, b):
    return (a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1], a[2] + b[2], a[3], a[4])


def quotation_list(request):
    stores = Store.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.all()
    # indice
    index_store = {store.id: index for index, store in enumerate(stores)}
    index_product = {product.id: index for index,
                     product in enumerate(products)}
    # dados para o template
    cabecalho = ["Lojas"] + [store.store for store in stores]
    linhas = [([product.product] + [None for store in stores] + [(0, 0, 0, None, product.product)])
              for product in products] + [["Subtotal"] + [(0, 0, 0, store.store, None) for store in stores]
                                          + [(0, 0, 0, None, None)]]

    for pev in Quotation.objects.all():
        total = pev.price * pev.quantity

        i0 = index_product[pev.product_id]
        i1 = index_store[pev.store_id] + 1
        valor = (pev.price, pev.quantity, total, pev.store, pev.product)

        linhas[i0][i1] = valor

        # Subtotal da linha
        linhas[i0][len(stores) + 1] = soma_tuplas(
            linhas[i0][len(stores) + 1], valor)

        # Subtotal da coluna
        linhas[len(products)][i1] = soma_tuplas(
            linhas[len(products)][i1], valor)

        # Total da tabela
        linhas[len(products)][len(stores) + 1] = soma_tuplas(
            linhas[len(products)][len(stores) + 1], valor)

    # retorna o menor preço de cada produto
    # a quantidade, total e loja também estão nesta lista
    mais_barato = []
    for linha in linhas:
        mais_barato.append(min(linha[1:]))

    # print(linhas[i0][len(stores) + 1])

    # destaca os menores preços no template
    mb = 0
    if request.GET.get('mais_barato', False):
        mb = 1

    # mostra somente os menores preços
    smb = 0
    if request.GET.get('somente_mais_barato', False):
        smb = 1

    linhas_mais_barato = zip(linhas, mais_barato)

    # mostra os produtos mais baratos, a quantidade e o total
    bqt = 0
    if request.GET.get('quantidade_e_total', False):
        linhas_mais_barato = sorted(linhas_mais_barato,
                                    key=lambda store: str(store[1][3]))  # sort by store
        bqt = 1

    context = {
        'cabecalho': cabecalho,
        'linhas_mais_barato': linhas_mais_barato,
        'mb': mb,
        'smb': smb,
        'bqt': bqt,
    }
    return render(request, 'core/quotation_list.html', context)
```

#### template

```
{% for linha, mais_barato in linhas_mais_barato %}
    <tr>
        {% for item in linha %}
            {% if bqt == 0 %}
                {% if forloop.first %}
                    <td>{{ item }}</td>
                {% elif forloop.last %}
                    <td>   </td>
                {% else %}
                    {% if mb == 1 %}
                        {% if mais_barato == item %}
                            <td class="text-center" style="border: 1px solid #f07746; background-color: #fbddd1;">{{ item.0 }}</td>
                        {% else %}
                            <td class="text-center">{{ item.0 }}</td>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% elif smb == 1 %}
                        {% if mais_barato == item %}
                            <td class="text-center">{{ item.0 }}</td>
                        {% else %}
                            <td>   </td>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% elif bqt == 0 %}
                        <td class="text-center">{{ item.0 }}</td>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% if bqt == 1 %}
            <td>{{ mais_barato.4 }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ mais_barato.0 }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ mais_barato.1 }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ mais_barato.2 }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ mais_barato.3 }}</td>
        {% endif %}
```

Faltou eu explicar uma coisa: na página eu estou retornando os seguintes valores

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gerados pelo seguinte código do template:

```
{% if bqt == 1 %}
    <td>{{ mais_barato.4 }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{ mais_barato.0 }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{ mais_barato.1 }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{ mais_barato.2 }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{ mais_barato.3 }}</td>
{% endif %}
```

E que por sua vez foi gerado a partir de

#### views.py

```
# retorna o menor preço de cada produto
# a quantidade, total e loja também estão nesta lista
mais_barato = []
for linha in linhas:
    mais_barato.append(min(linha[1:]))
```

O problema é que, como eu estou usando os valores da lista `mais_barato` (talvez erroneamente), eu preciso de:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: @mgibsonbr criei uma nova pergunta. Mas creio que está quase pronto, aproveitando tudo que vc já explicou, creio que só precisaria retrabalhar em cima das listas.

Comment: Eu sei que pra você talvez seria melhor só adaptar o código atual para completar com o que você quer, mas dei uma resposta sugerindo uma abordagem diferente. Pois a estrutura de sua tabela nesse caso é completamente diferente daquela que originou a pergunta. Se você está escolhendo entre uma estrutura e outra - baseado nessa variável `bqt` - eu sugiro alternar entre um código e outro no view também por essa mesma variável (o código novo a acrescentar é pequeno, e a performance da sua página deve ser bem menor sem o código desnecessário).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embora seu código atual seja adequado para uma tabela que cruza produtos com lojas (tal como na [sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96493/215) que originou esse código todo), essa sua nova estrutura se beneficiaria mais de uma estratégia diferente. Em particular, é possível fazer com que o "trabalho pesado" seja feito pelo próprio banco de dados, e o tratamento na view seja bem menor. Não somente a performance deve melhorar, como o código que você precisaria escrever seria muito menor.

### Refatorando

Seu caso é bastante semelhante a [essa outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52125/215). Adaptado, ficaria:

1. *Imports* e variáveis auxiliares:

   ```
   from django.db.models import F, Min, FloatField

   pega_total = F('price') * F('quantity')
   pega_total.output_field = FloatField()
   ```
2. Começa a busca pelo `Quotation`:

   ```
   Quotation.objects.
   ```
3. Encontra o menor preço de cada produto, e calcula o total (preço x quantidade):

   ```
   .annotate(menor=Min('product__quotation__price'), total=pega_total).
   ```
4. Filtra apenas os itens cujo preço é igual àquele mínimo:

   ```
   .filter(price=F('menor')).
   ```
5. [se suportado] Elimina duplicatas (duas lojas que oferecem o produto pelo mesmo valor); não suportado por todos os BDs:

   ```
   .distinct('product').
   ```

   (No SQLite deu `NotImplementedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend`)
6. Ordena pela loja:

   ```
   .order_by('store__store').
   ```
7. Pega os valores que te interessam para montar a tabela:

   ```
   .values('product__product', 'price', 'quantity', 'total', 'store__store')
   ```

Assim, você já obtém os dados que você precisa pra sua tabela em uma única *query*:

```
from django.db.models import F, Min, FloatField

pega_total = F('price') * F('quantity')
pega_total.output_field = FloatField()

qs = Quotation.objects.all().\
         annotate(menor=Min('product__quotation__price'), total=pega_total).\
         filter(price=F('menor')).\
         distinct('product').\
         order_by('store__store').\
         values('product__product', 'price', 'quantity', 'total', 'store__store')

context = { "linhas":list(qs) }
```

E no template:

```
{% for linha in linhas %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ linha.product__product }}</td>
    <td>{{ linha.price }}</td>
    <td>{{ linha.quantity }}</td>
    <td>{{ linha.total }}</td>
    <td>{{ linha.store__store }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

### Acrescentando subtotal e total

Como os dados já vêm ordenados por loja, calcular o subtotal é fácil: basta ir seguindo linha por linha e acumulando, e quando a loja mudar (ou as lojas acabarem), incluir uma linha especial para o subtotal:

```
qs = ...

subtotal = 0
total = 0
ultima_loja = None

linhas = []
for linha in qs:
    if ultima_loja is not None and ultima_loja != linha['store__store']:
        linhas.append({ 'subtotal':subtotal })
        subtotal = 0
    linhas.append(linha)
    ultima_loja = linha['store__store']
    subtotal += linha['total']
    total += linha['total']

if ultima_loja is not None:
    linhas.append({ 'subtotal':subtotal })
linhas.append({ 'total':total })

context = { "linhas":linhas }
```

E no template:

```
{% for linha in linhas %}
<tr>
    {% if linha.product__product %}
        <td>{{ linha.product__product }}</td>
        <td>{{ linha.price }}</td>
        <td>{{ linha.quantity }}</td>
        <td>{{ linha.total }}</td>
        <td>{{ linha.store__store }}</td>
    {% elif linha.subtotal %}
        <td></td><td></td><td></td>
        <td class="subtotal">{{ linha.subtotal }}</td>
        <td>SUBTOTAL</td>
    {% else %}
        <td></td><td></td><td></td>
        <td class="total">{{ linha.total }}</td>
        <td>TOTAL</td>
    {% endif %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

---

**Nota**: se tiver curiosidade, esse é o SQL que a *query* sugerida nessa resposta gera (exceto pela parte do `distinct` que não funcionou aqui):

```
SELECT
    "app_product"."product",
    "app_quotation"."price",
    "app_quotation"."quantity",
    "app_store"."store",
    ("app_quotation"."price" * "app_quotation"."quantity") AS "total" 
FROM "app_quotation" 
    INNER JOIN "app_product" ON ( "app_quotation"."product_id" = "app_product"."id" )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "app_quotation" T3 ON ( "app_product"."id" = T3."product_id" )
    INNER JOIN "app_store" ON ( "app_quotation"."store_id" = "app_store"."id" )
GROUP BY
    "app_quotation"."id",
    "app_quotation"."product_id",
    "app_quotation"."store_id",
    "app_quotation"."price",
    "app_quotation"."quantity",
    ("app_quotation"."price" * "app_quotation"."quantity"),
    "app_product"."product",
    "app_store"."store"
HAVING "app_quotation"."price" = (MIN(T3."price"))
ORDER BY "app_store"."store" ASC
```

Comment: Olá mgibsonbr demorei pra rever este post, porque acabei mexendo com outras coisas. A primeira parte do if no template não está funcionando, ou seja, não está retornando os produtos, somente os subtotais.

Comment: @RegisdaSilva Demorei pra responder, pois estava testando o template. No final o template estava certo, foi o loop no view que eu esqueci de acrescentar os produtos em si na lista... :P Testei agora, deve estar tudo certo.

Comment: agora ficou perfeito!!! Muito obrigado mesmo. Só mais uma coisinha, tem uns subtotais que deram estouro de valor, exemplo, 17.150000000000002 mesmo sendo 3,43 x 5. Tentei com round() mas não foi.

Comment: Isso é problema de ponto flutuante, [não se pode representar `17.15` precisamente em `double`](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=049055046049053), então fazer `round` não vai adiantar. Você precisa formatar o número antes de exibir em vez disso. Posso estar enganado, mas não me parece ter meios de fazer isso em templates sem o uso de bibliotecas externas (!), então o jeito é fazer no view também... Tipo `"{:.2f}".format(numero)`. Ou então criar uma *template tag* ou *filter* próprios pra isso (nunca fiz isso antes, mas não parece difícil).

Comment: resolvi no template dessa forma `{{ linha.total|floatformat:2 }}`

Comment: Que bom, acho que eu estava consultando uma referência antiga. É lógico que o Django não ia deixar de ter uma funcionalidade dessas, tão básica e tão necessária... :)